# Asp.net c# Class library dlls right version not loading correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, class-library

I created a class library and called id sharepointClassSample library.
It has a reference to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll version 16.1.0.0 along other ones.

I compiled the library and moved the resulted files to a folder called myLibrary

I created a project and referenced the sharepointClassSample.dll within the myLibrary folder.
Compiled the project and all the dlls needed by the sharepointClassSample.dll library were copied to my project bin/debug folder.

But the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll copied on my folder is 15.0.0.0

Is there a way or setting within the Class library project that allow to specify the right dlls versions to be copied when the library is referenced?

Comment: The question is not answerable in the current state. Please either try to come up with [mre], or at very least update the post to be clear what " dlls version" means (version of native dll, version as part of the strong name of an assembly, some other "version" of assembly, timestamps?) along with expected/actual list of versions, potentially include relevant parts of web.config.

Comment: Ok, I will change it.

Comment: It is changed now, I hope you can answer it, can you?

Comment: No, I can't answer. You are up to very long debugging session to figure out which dependency bring another version of the DLL. You'd likely need to reconfigure logging level for build and grep through the build logs. Give it a day or two :( if your project is big... If it is just one class library you may find offending dependency in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to use [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) to use the specified version.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                               publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                               culture="neutral" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                              newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In addition, redirect rules can specify to redirect within a certain version range

2. You can also use the NuGet package manager: Add the required DLL using the NuGet package manager in the class library project and specify the required version.
3. Manually add DLL: Copy the DLL file to the class library project and add a reference in the project.

When referencing a library, setting the build action to copy to output directory on the reference properties does not result in a version change.